# Loop through a cursor in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, cursor, where-clause

I would like to understand how I can use the content of a cursor in a Where clause of a SQL query.

I tried to run the code below and I get no result.

The field salescostindex allows me to recognise the specific sales and costs for each transaction with a customer. Now I need to understand when the costs are booked to a cost centre and the corresponding sales are booked to another. This is why I need the looping, I need to exclude a cost centre from the sales account 100001 for each selection of the same cost centre in the cost account 200001.
Now when I use a cost centre where I know this is happening in the routine, this works, nevertheless when I let it loop across the cursor no result is returned.`

Here is a sample of the data.
in the SalesCostIndex field you see that number 000010, 000105, 002008 appear in ledger 200001 in one cost centre and in ledger 100001 in another cost centre.
So I would like to have a query that picks up only the salescostindex that appear in ledger 200001 in one cost centre and in ledger 100001 in a different cost centre.
Now the cost centres in the real dataset are more than 100.

```
+------------+------------+----------------+--------+-------------+
|    Date    | CostCentre | SalesCostIndex | Ledger | SalesAmount |
+------------+------------+----------------+--------+-------------+
| 2018-09-21 |        100 |         000010 | 100001 |        -100 |
| 2018-09-01 |        100 |         000105 | 100001 |        -154 |
| 2018-08-23 |        100 |         002008 | 200001 |          67 |
| 2018-08-23 |        100 |         001525 | 200001 |          45 |
| 2018-07-21 |        101 |         001731 | 100001 |        -101 |
| 2018-08-23 |        101 |         000010 | 200001 |          80 |
| 2018-08-23 |        101 |         001964 | 200001 |          75 |
| 2018-08-23 |        101 |         002001 | 200001 |         112 |
| 2018-08-23 |        102 |         002245 | 200001 |         210 |
| 2018-08-23 |        102 |         000105 | 200001 |         125 |
| 2018-08-23 |        102 |         002008 | 100001 |         -91 |
| 2018-08-27 |        102 |         002115 | 200001 |          25 |
+------------+------------+----------------+--------+-------------+
```

I could not try an approach that included inserting into a temporary table. This is because I don't have a write access to the database and I can't create objects, hence I have to stick only to results from `SELECT` statements or any statement that does not write to the database.

```
DECLARE @CC VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE CCcursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT DISTINCT CostCentre FROM
    LedgerTransactions
    WHERE   
    Ledger='200001' and
    Date = '2018-08-23' and
    CostCentre like '1__'   

OPEN CCcursor
FETCH NEXT FROM CCcursor
INTO @CC

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN

    SELECT CostCentre,
           SalesCostIndex,
           Sum(SalesAmount) as TotalSales
    FROM
    LedgerTransactions
    WHERE        
    Ledger='100001' and
    CostCentre not in (@CC) and
    SalesCostIndex in
        (Select Distinct SalesCostIndex
        FROM LedgerTransactions
        WHERE        
        Ledger='200001' and
        Date = '2018-08-23' AND
        CostCentre in (@CC))
    GROUP BY
    CostCentre, SalesCostIndex

FETCH NEXT FROM CCcursor
INTO @CC

END

CLOSE CCcursor
```

Comment: Use Print to output the results of the select statement?

Comment: oh sand why are you using a cursor. A join would do this.

Comment: And in fact the cursor is unnecessary, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Just get a list of all the centers into 1 string?  If so you can do that in one select statement.  What  version of SQL are you using?

Comment: Well I just tried to post a test code to see if there was a solution to the looping.
in reality I need then to compare entries across different cost centres and accounts.
I need to loop because for each statement I need to exclude a cost centre

Comment: The version is SQL Server 2008

Comment: Please edit your question to include representative sample data.  Also, please share your actual goal - I suspect that this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I edited my question, is it more understandable or I need to add something?

Comment: @EliseoDiFolco, you still need to add representative sample data so that people who are trying to help you can set up a test case and see the behavior you see.  You also need to describe your larger issue (see my link regarding XY Problems) so that we can all see that a cursor is your __*only*__ possible solution.  I, personally, __*never*__ use a cursor if I can avoid it, and so far (almost 30 years now) I've been able to avoid it.

Comment: @Brian,         Hopefully now it is clearer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this meets your needs:

```
Select
    SalesCostIndex            
From dbo.Cost_Index As ci1
    Inner Join dbo.Cost_Index As ci2
        On ci2.SalesCostIndex = ci1.SalesCostIndex
    Where ci1.Ledger = '100001'
    And ci2.Ledger = '200001'
    And ci1.CostCentre <> ci2.CostCentre
```

Comment: You're very welcome - I'm glad that it worked for you.  Death to cursors! ;)